# How can I skip rendering a file if the fields aren't defined?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a bunch of templates (*t*) I'm rendering for a bunch of cases (*c*), so, in general, *t × c* templates get generated.

```
for template in templates:
    for case in cases:
        rendered = template.render(case.data)
        save(case.filename, rendered)
```

Now we have a new requirement, where some of the combinations don't matter, like 3 of them. I don't want files rendered in those rare cases. *(t × c - 3)*

I could write some control flow code (nested inside the for loops), but then that code would have to be more tightly coupled to the template than I want it to be, so I'm trying to figure out a better way to do it.

What I think I want is something in the jinja template to say "sorry, this template failed", and then the exception can be handled at the generation time. (also inside the for loops, but less decisioning there) I came up with this, and it's kind of working, but I don't like it:

```
{{ foo if foo is defined else 1 / 0 }}
```

This causes an exception, but it's not a helpful exception. Is there a cleaner way of generating an exception in jinja?

Instead of an exception, is there a way to report that a template shouldn't be generated within jinja?

(Should I just avoid this type of things and just put the logic in the generation code)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a filter that looked something like this:

```
from jinja2 import Undefined

def skip_if_not_defined(value):
    if type(value) is Undefined:
        raise SkipTemplateException()
```

So when I used it

```
{{ blah|skip_if_not_defined }}
```

it would raise an exception which can be caught.